# UICollectionView. What did I miss?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I'm trying to make custom keyboard with collection view on it.

In my KeyboardViewController.m I have

```
UIView *keyboardView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[keyboardView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:keyboardView];
```

to load XIB with custom interface.

In KeyboardView i have a `UICollectionView` with custom cells and custom method to initialize it

```
- (void)loadKeyboard {

    NSLog(@"test");

    self.tabsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab4.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab5.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab6.png"], nil];

    self.tabsCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.tabsCollectionView.delegate = self;

    self.tabsCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.tabsCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TabCollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
             forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
    [self.tabsCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

I tested it several times and I found that `UICollectionView` delegate methods like `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` are not being called. What did I miss?

Comment: Did you implement the other required data source methods such as the one that indicates how many items are in each section? And does it return a non-zero value?

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, [tabsArray count] returns 6. I've placed `NSLog`s over all this methods, but they are not being called anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that the collection view is actually connected to your `tabsCollectionView` outlet?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm pretty sure

Comment: Be sure. Use the debugger. Check if it's nil or not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: make sure you connected delegate and data source from your XIB

Comment: Did you implement and return a non-zero value from `- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`?